# Using Cayley hamilton therom to find the value of matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse, hamilton-equations

[This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ec8y.png) where I don't understand how the equations get cancelled and the answers comes out to be $A^2+A+I$. When I am doing the same thing there $7A^4$ which is't cancelled.

Comment: you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. The solution is that since, $A^3-5A^2+7A-3I=0$ by the theorem the first term becomes zero and the solution arrives when  we the follow the steps.